Expected value issue.
I buy a stock at x value, then I will either sell it at +20 (take profit) or -10 (stop loss). Considering that the probability of hitting each of the 2 targets is relative to the distance (am I wrong here?), then we have.
Probability of hitting +20 target is:
$P_{profit}= 1 - \left(\frac{20}{20 + 10}\right) = \frac{1}{3}$%
Probability of hitting -10 target is:
$P_{loss}= 1 - \left(\frac{10}{20 + 10}\right) = \frac{2}{3}$%
At this point, if we repeat that same style of trading 100 times, we have an expected value of 0 because:
$EV=20*P_{profit} - 10*P_{loss}= 20*\frac{1}{3} - 10*\frac{2}{3}=0$
Now, where I have the problem in my calculations is in the following scenario.
I buy 2 stocks at x value, if I hit my stop-loss at -10 I sell both of them (or 1 if this is the one that has remained to my hands). At 10 take-profit I sell 1. At 20 take-profit I sell the second one. Now, I am not sure of my mathematics, but since always the probabilities to hit a target are relative to the distance, I would somehow expect to see that again the expected value is 0?
I tried 2 different cases that are probably wrong.
Case 1
The first one was to calculate directly the expected value by hitting directly the +20 or -10 targets:
If the price hits the +20 profit target, then the profit is 1 stock at the +10 target plus 1 stock at the +20 target, total profit of +30.
If the price hits the -10 stop-loss target we lose: 2 * (-10)= -20.
In that case we would have an EV of (30 - 20) = 10 but this shouldn't be correct as the price might go at +10 (take first profit there) and return back to hit the -10 (which is the stop-loss) resulting in a $0 of total profit. That case is not taking place in the above EV calculation.
Case 2
The second way I was thinking to calculate it was to calculate the EV in 2 different scenarios. One for the price to go to either -10 or +10 and the second scenario for the price to go from +10 to either +20 or -10 and then probably somehow add the EVs? Again here I am doing something wrong.
Can someone help me or point me to the correct direction on where to look? My math suck a bit :(.

This is not clear.  What distribution are you supposing for the stock price?

@lulu I am not sure what you mean by distribution. The stock is able to fluctuate the price at any value but we are only interested for the target values. Would you mind sharing the place you don't find clear so that I can perhaps correct the question?

You are speaking about probabilities, so there needs to be a set of possible outcomes and a set of probabilities for those outcomes.  Those probabilities are usually described by a distribution, though if there are only finitely many outcomes you can just list the probabilities.  Of course, we have no idea what distribution you have in mind.

Your model could be a symmetric random walk or Brownian motion.  Starting at $0$, the probabilities of hitting $+20$ before $-10$ is $\frac13$ (no percentage), and of hitting $-10$ before $+20$ is $\frac23$, as your calculations suggest.
Take your idea of buying two at $0$ and perhaps selling one at $+10$.  Your case 2 calculation gives the correct answer and your case 1 calculation should have been:

Starting at $0$, the probability of hitting $+10$ before $-10$ is $\frac12$.  If that happens, you sell one for a gain of $+10$ and hold the other.

Starting at $+10$, the probability of hitting $+20$ before $-10$ is then $\frac23$.  If that happens you sell the other one for $+20$.
Starting at $+10$, the probability of hitting $-10$ before $+20$ is then $\frac13$.  If that happens you sell the other one for $-10$.


Starting at $0$, the probability of hitting $-10$ before $+10$ is $\frac12$.  If that happens, you sell both for a combined $-10-10=-20$.

So the overall expectation is $$\frac12\times\left(\frac23\times(+10+20)+\frac13(+10-10)\right) + \frac12 \times(-20) = 0.$$
Your model is a martingale so this should not be a surprise.
